# angularjs restart css animation

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am using angularjs and I am trying to trigger an animation each time a model property is changed.
My controller:

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data.counter = 0;
    $scope.addCount = function() {
        $scope.data.counter ++;
    };

}
```

My html:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-click="addCount()">add count</button>
    <div class="bgimage"></div>
</div>
```

My css:

```
.bgimage {
      background-image: url('../images/a.png');
      background-position: right;
      background-size: 16px 14px;
      width: 16px;
      height: 14px;
}
.bgimage.pulse {
    -webkit-animation: pulse 1s both;
    -moz-animation: pulse 1s both;
    -o-animation: pulse 1s both;
    animation: pulse 1s both;
}
```

I want that each time 'count' changes, the 'bgimage' element will be 'pulsed'.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I did a little [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eiaXbfvDLAaPEUf13IRw?p=preview), using JS Animations and animating based on your counter variable. You can extend that example as you wish. I guess you just wanted to pulsate once (as using 'both' in your animation).

You could also go for CSS keyframes animations, as described [here](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html)

Comment: thanks! Is there any way to restart animation from the beginning if I click on the button rapidly, i.e. before the previous animation is finished?

Answer (score 1):

Remove and add the pulse class from the element so it will be animated once again.

Comment: How? Should I do it with a directive?? How to integrate it with AngularJS?

Comment: This can be done with `showThing = false; $timeout(() => { showThing = true; }, 1);` and then using that variable in the view with an `ng-show`, and then apply some animations to the appropriate classes (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow#animations)